# Javascript - Validate names

Tags: javascript, html, validation

This sounds like a duplicate thread but it is not (as far as I have searched :D).

```
<body>

Player 1, enter name: <input type="text" id="P1_NAME"> <a id="P1_NAMEERROR"></a>

</body>

<script>

// Validate names

    document.getElementById("P1_NAME").onkeypress = function () {
    var P1_NAME = document.getElementById("P1_NAME").value;
    if (((/^[A-Za-z]+$/).test(P1_NAME) == false) && (P1_NAME != "")) {
        document.getElementById("P1_NAMEERROR").innerHTML = "Invalid name";
    }
    if (((/^[A-Za-z]+$/).test(P1_NAME) == true) && (P1_NAME != "")) {
        document.getElementById("P1_NAMEERROR").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (P1_NAME == "") {
        document.getElementById("P1_NAMEERROR").innerHTML = "Cannot be left blank";
    }
}

</script>
```

Using the above code, the name will be considered invalid if it contains numbers and symbols. Which means, "bOb78" and "yU%##" will be invalid.

But that means that the user can just type "zhqsdakjzs" and it will be considered valid.

So is there a way to really validate if a name is real?

**Edit: "real" meaning that the name is not a nonsensical string of text like "sudialrhsdd", "chriiiiiiistooopheeerrr", etc.**

Comment: Define "name" and "real". In the general case, the answer is "no".

Comment: Of course not. What is a *real* name? In 1991, a Swedish couple named their child Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116 (Pronounced "albin") -- http://www.neatorama.com/2008/05/19/10-strangest-names-evar/

Comment: what do you mean by "real"?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "Real" meaning that the name cannot be nonsensical strings of text like "yyuuyzasastksd".

Comment: @chris, "nonsensical" depends on the context. For instance, `Yuu` is a valid Japanese first name, but might appear as nonsensical to a non-Japanese reader.

Comment: @Faust - Awesome link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a database with a black list of false names and compare the input with the stored names.

Comment: Ya but won't it take forever?

Comment: I'd rather make a database with real names to check against...